# How can loop through a list from a certain index?

Tags: python, list, loops

I found the answer here but it doesn't work for me *[Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)*

I'm trying to loop from the second index

```
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi']

for indx, val in enumerate(ints, start=1):
    print indx, val

for i in range(len(ints)):
   print i, ints[1]
```

My output is this

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 hi
0 3
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 3
```

I need to get the first integer printed out at index 1 and loop through to the end.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple way is to use python's slice notation - see the section in the basic tutorial. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

`for item in ints[1:]:`

This will iterate your list skipping the 0th element. Since you don't actually need the index, this implementation is clearer than ones that maintain the index needlessly

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
for idx, val in enumerate(ints[1:], start=1)
    print idx, val
```

Or

```
for i in range(1, len(ints)):
    print i, ints[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve. To my understanding, if you just want to loop through the list starting at the second element you can do this:

```
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi']

for i in range(1,len(ints)):
    print i, ints[i]
```

output:

```
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 hi
```

Alternatively, if you want to loop through all elements, but print the indices starting from 1 instead of 0:

```
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi']

for i in range(len(ints)):
    print i+1, ints[i]
```

output:

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 hi
```

Or using `enumerate()` going through all elements, but print the indices starting at 1 instead of 0:

```
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi']

for i, el in enumerate(ints):
    print (i+1), el
```

output:

```
1 1
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 hi
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itertools.islice`:

```
import itertools

for idx, el in enumerate(itertools.islice(ints, 1, None), start=1):
    print(idx, el)
```

Or if you just want to skip the first element:

```
for idx, el in enumerate(ints):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    print(idx, el)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for iterables too (not only lists):

```
def enumerate_from(start_index, iterable):
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
        if i >= start_index:
            yield i, x
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this:

```
index = 3 
steps = 1 
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi']   
for val in range(index, len(ints), steps):
    print(ints[val])
```

Result:

> 5,hi

but the easy way:

```
index = 3
ints = [1, 3, 4, 5, 'hi'] 
for item in ints[index:]:
    print(item)
```